# how To use it create a class that extends Application and override its onCreate() method

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Errors:

```
Application cannot be resolved to a type

SharedPreferences cannot be resolved to a type`

the method override must override or implement a super type method

Multiple markers at this line

PreferenceManager cannot be resolved
```

Program:

```
 package com.su.vapour;

public class Common extends Application {  

    public static String[] email_arr;
    private static SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        List<String> emailList = getEmailList();
        email_arr = emailList.toArray(new String[emailList.size()]);
    }

    private List<String> getEmailList() {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                lst.add(account.name);
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Seems you did not import `android.app.Application`. Do you know a bit of Java?

Comment: i know java littlebit just basic

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `import` statements for the classes and interfaces that you are referencing in this Java file, such as `android.app.Application` and `android.content.SharedPreferences`.

`import` statements are a fairly basic Java concept. I strongly encourage you to go learn Java, particularly the [key areas](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/02/java-good-parts-version.html) that are needed for Android app development.